# jq inserts .o instead of .c files in the compile_commands.json "file" field

Tags: json, regex, jq

I manage to create a `CommandsFile.txt` that looks like this:

```
  /cygwin/c/Dev/bin/tricore-gcc.exe   -isystem     all_inc     -W     -Wall  (plus a bunch of other flags)  -c     software/ProjectA/src/file1.c     -o     _objs/ccLib/file1.o
  /cygwin/c/Dev/bin/tricore-gcc.exe   -isystem     all_inc     -W     -Wall  (plus a bunch of other flags)  -c     software/ProjectA/src/file2.c     -o     _objs/ccLib/file2.o
...
```

and I exploited `jq` for generating the `compile_commands.json` file in the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

cat CommandsFile.txt \
| grep -wE 'gcc|g\+\+' \
| grep -w '\-c' \
| ./jq-win64 -nR '[inputs|{directory:".", command:., file: match(" [^ ]+$").string[1:]}]' \
 > compile_commands.json
```

and it works like a charm, but the script fills the field `"file"` with `.o` instead of `.c` files:

```
...
  {
    "directory": ".",
    "command": "  /cygwin/c/Dev/bin/tricore-gcc.exe   -isystem     all_inc     -W     -Wall  (plus a bunch of other flags)  -c     software/ProjectA/src/file1.c     -o     _objs/ccLib/file1.o,
    "file": "_objs/ccLib/file1.o"
  },
  {
    "directory": ".",
    "command": "  /cygwin/c/Dev/bin/tricore-gcc.exe   -isystem     all_inc     -W     -Wall  (plus a bunch of other flags)  -c     software/ProjectA/src/file2.c     -o     _objs/ccLib/file2.o,
    "file": "_objs/ccLib/file2.o"  },
...
```

How shall I modified the script for having the `.c` files instead of the `.o` files in the field `"file"`?

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the problem here concerns the regex to use to capture the .c file (or files), so I'll focus on that.

If it's known there's at most one .c file, and that it is reasonably named (e.g., no embedded spaces), then it would be simplest to "capture" the filename along these lines:

```
capture("(^| )(?<c>[^ ]+[.]c)( |$)")
```

However, if there might be more than one .c file, then you could iteratively use the following "capture" expression:

```
capture("(^| )(?<c>[^ ]+[.]c)( |$)(?<etc>.*)")
```

Examples:

```
echo 'a.c b.c' |
  jq -R 'capture("(^| )(?<c>[^ ]+[.]c)( |$)(?<etc>.*)")'
```

produces:

```
{
  "c": "a.c",
  "etc": "b.c"
}
```

#### Multiple .c files

```
echo "a.c b.c" |
  jq -R '
  # emit a stream of filenames ending in .$suffix
  def filenames($suffix):
    def one:
      capture("(^| )(?<c>[^ ]+[.]"+$suffix+")( |$) *(?<etc>.*)");
    def names:
      one | .c, (.etc | names);
    names;

  filenames("c")'
```

produces:

```
"a.c"
"b.c"
```

Comment: Many thanks! However, if I use this `./jq-win64 -nR '[inputs|{directory:".", command:., file: capture("(^| )(?<c>[^ ]+[.]c)( |$)")'` I got the error: `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[inputs|{directory:".", command:., file: capture("(^| )(?<c>[^ ]+[.]c)( |$)") `

Comment: Use the -f option to avoid complications.